# Possible Villain motive for gaining omnipotence?

Tags: science-fiction

I've reached a dilemma regarding the motive of a villain I have recently created. I wanted to reach out to see if I can get any insight online to help me formulate ideas about it. Keep in mind that most of this is a work in progress and can change if I see fit.

The villain wishes to gain true omnipotence and control over time, reality, and the universe, but not for selfish reasons. I wan't the villain's motive to possibly be altruistic and even somewhat beneficial to the universe, however his method for gaining such a status, or perhaps even the status itself must be a major downside that effects the universe.

A possible idea I had would be that the villain wants omnipotence in order to elevate civilization itself to omnipotence, therefore creating an omnipresent, conflict-less, perfect civilization in which nothing bad ever happens. But what would be the major downside to that? How would that conflict with the balance of the universe?

Another idea I had was that He wants to gain omnipotence in order to dismantle it, because he believes nothing in the universe should be worthy of such a title, but again, how would this be disadvantageous to the universe?

The universe itself in this story is infinite. I won't go into the circumstances that caused it, but there is no need for the universe's inhabitants to worry about the universe ending one day. The universe itself is actually the soul of an entity that exists in a realm outside of time and space in endless meditation. I'm thinking that the path to omnipotence can relate to gaining access to this realm, and interacting (maybe even replacing) the entity in question.

I've omitted a whole lot of stuff about this world, but the things relevant to this concept should all be available. If there are any follow up questions regarding extra info I'll be happy to answer them. I appreciate any help someone can give me on this topic, and if not, I hope you at least found this entertaining to read.

Comment: Isn't this basically the plot of the new Avengers movie? Thanos isn't doing it for himself, he wants to save the Universe.

Comment: Typically "motives of one individual" are off topic on this site.  There's rarely a right answer to such questions, because the individuals are myriad.  My recommendation would  be to start by shaping the villain then worry about what he's going to do.  Consider looking into the Jungian archetypes for source material.  A trickster will have *very* different reasons for achieving omnipotence than a outcast would, or a devil.

Comment: In Peter F. Hamilton's Void Trilogy, a faction of ANA attempt to utilize an alien construct to alter the nature of space-time. The result would have been an expanding sphere of changed-space that would consume the universe. They were presented as the villan, and should they have succeeded, they would have created a universe in which anyone can know and have anything. Maybe it would have been a good thing for some, or potentially most, but the premise was that new alien civilizations wouldn't arise and certain cultures would be destroyed.

Comment: It seems often portrayed that complete control over the universe always has this downside to it.

Comment: I don't want to rule the universe. I just think it could be more sensibly organised.

- Eliezer Yudkowsky

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this question has much to do with worldbuilding. This seems to be more of a character-based question, with the worldbuilding merely serving as context. Writing stack exchange: https://writing.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this.

Comment: I've voted to close because you're basically asking us to write your story for you.  WB.SE is about helping you develop consistent rules for a world in which many stories may be told, not help you write one story.  Please review our [help] and our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and questions being [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).

Comment: Marvel calling, they want their plot back

Comment: Does this "universe" already have a being with these powers?  Or has it previously had such a being?

Comment: @TheWeaselSagas [writing.se] is about *techniques*. "What to write" questions are specifically off topic there, for much of the same reasons why character building questions are off topic here. Please don't suggest asking on other sites without making sure that the question has a reasonable chance of being on topic on the suggested site.

Answer (score 7):

> A possible idea I had would be that the villain wants omnipotence in order to elevate civilization itself to omnipotence, therefore creating an omnipresent, conflict-less, perfect civilization in which nothing bad ever happens.

That means he's a Utopian.

> But what would be the major downside to that?

A **LOT**.

http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Matrix_Beta_Versions

> The first Matrix (the Paradise Matrix) was designed to be a perfect human world, where none would suffer and everyone would be happy. It was designed as a Utopian realm where one's desires, namely the mind connected to it, would manifest. However, human minds did not accept this construct, and scores of humans rejected the program.
>
> Agent Smith (relating this story to the incarcerated and drugged Morpheus) noted that "it was a disaster, entire crops were lost",[1] implying that many humans died because of their inability to accept this first Matrix as a real concept. Essentially, humans in the Paradise Matrix, even without memories or knowledge of life outside of it, could inherently tell that it was "too good to be true".

Think also of Marxism (the Worker's Paradise), National Socialism (the Aryan Paradise), and the death & destruction waged to bring about those so called Utopias and the 19th century Utopian socialist societies (all of which collapsed).

Answer (score 2):

- Fixing one specific tragedy, possibly a crime, at the expense of all others.
  An accident or murder killed his family. Now he wants to **alter the structure of the timeline** to un-make that accident and live happily ever after with them, even if reality itself would unravel from the change.
- Protecting people from their own stupidity.
  The people on this planet, or that one, or that one, are living an unsustainable lifestyle. Don't they see that the ecosystem will totally collapse collapse in a mere 10^3 years? Changes will become widespread and devastating in a few 10^1 years. Somebody has to do something. He wants to **make them understand** why that is wrong. No more SUVs. No more Frappucinos in disposable cups. No more 2,000 square foot air-conditioned mansions in a desert. No more meat on the menu every single day. But they don't want to understand unless he comes up with some sort of mind control.

Answer (score 2):

> A possible idea I had would be that the villain wants omnipotence in order to elevate civilization itself to omnipotence, therefore creating an omnipresent, conflict-less, perfect civilization in which nothing bad ever happens. But 
>   what would be the major downside to that? How would that conflict with the
>   balance of the universe?

A really good downside to omnipotence in this situation could be that it somehow strips away free will - especially if this makes everyone omnipotent and omnipresent, as it would likely strip away joy as nobody could experience anything new, being omnipotent and omnipresent.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to gain omnipotence because he is a nice guy, and wants to end the injustices that cause people misery, grief, despair and tears. No more children kidnapped and raped to death. Heck, no more children killed in car crashes or floods, tornadoes or hurricanes, house fires or airplane malfunctions. Not just kids, nobody at all killed that way, at any age.

In fact, nobody raped, period. Or shot or stabbed or beaten up, or threatened with that. And no more incurable diseases, either. Nobody spending their lives in wheelchairs, nobody born mentally disabled or missing limbs.

We're going to stop bullying in school, too, that serves no purpose whatsoever. And food poisoning. Why is there food poisoning? What necessity does food poisoning serve? What necessity does ANY disease serve? Why should people have to be cautious about sanitation and cleanliness, isn't that a waste of their precious life? Isn't that time they could be having fun, writing poetry or painting instead of washing up?

The same goes for infirmities, of course. Why should people grow old and progressively less cognizant and increasingly feeble? Would there be something wrong with people staying, say, a fit 26 for the rest of their life?

And then, why should they die if they are a fit 26? Wouldn't that be a travesty? They should live forever. Of course there might be some problems with that, and people not wanting to give up control of their family, institutions, etc. But he is omnipotent, he can fix that. Tone down the greed and selfishness in humans, so they **want** to retire after their 30 year career. And the universe is infinite, it can handle an infinite number of people that live forever.

That is why he needs to be omnipotent, to end all the things he sees as injustice. But of course, as I have tried to demonstrate, that is a slippery slope.